# Mass reset password

Tags: change-password

I've got a lot of user and I've  to reset their passwords.

How can I reset their passwords in mass?

Can I do it with "Jitterbit" or "Data Loader"?

Answer (score 1):

You can't reset password using Data loader or Jitterbit.One way is to create a list view under Users and then select the users and then click on Reset Password button or look into to  this [app exchange product](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4QBQEA3)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by way of Apex.  Here's how to reset one user to a specific password value:

```
List<User> ul;
...
ul = [Select ID, Username From User Where username=:username];

if ( ! ul.isEmpty() ) {
    User u = ul.get(0);
    System.setPassword(u.ID,password);
    ...
```

This could be done for more than one user by creating a Select statement that picks out the ones you want to update (and adding a for loop).